# How to share local network links with team messenger?

Tags: networking, skype, links, local, slack

I'm working in advertising agency, and we often need to share local links within Windows 8 and 10 network. Files are big, so you can't attach them to messages.

For communication we use slack and Skype, but the problem is that click on link like

```
\\SERVER\path\to\some\folder
```

nothing happens. Parser inside mesenger understands that it is link, higlights it, but doesn't open it.

Workflow now looks like 
<kbd>Shift</kbd> + Right click on file → copy as path → paste to Skype → copy from Skype to Windows explorer → remove **""** from path → open file

when you do it 20 times a day it's frustrating.

Can you suggest more convenient way to share links with other team members?

Comment: Do you use Outlook at all?

Comment: we use gmail for mail, and don't use outlook. We have a team chat in skype and it's easiesr to paste links there and discuss

Comment: Try using this `"<file:{server link}>"` So it will look like this is the above is the path `"<file:{\\SERVER\path\to\some\folder}>"` give it a test.

Comment: no, it's not ever recognized as link(

Comment: Please clarify what _local_ really means. Are you expecting some magic file transfer to a peer which has no access to \\SERVER\?

Comment: have you tried appending the path with `file:` like `file:\\SERVER\path\to\some\folder` ?

Comment: no. you can navigate to these files from window explorer, go to other local network computer and follow full path to desired file. To ease this process we send links to each other via skype

Comment: Just edit the question and make it clear, where files are stored? Using which software you access them now? an some more relevent info.

Comment: Version of Skype may matter? https://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-archive/UNC-links-highlighted-but-are-not-clickable/td-p/3651821

Comment: There are actually 3 slashes. `file:///filepath/filename`

Comment: @Narzard none of links starting with file:/ regonized as links by skype and slack

Comment: @ＳＡＮＤＥＥＰ we have a local network of 6 computers. files are stored in shared folders on each computer. We need to share links to these files amng workgroup. how it's done now is described in top post, we need to copy link like \\SERVER\path\to\some\folder from skype to clipboard, then switch to windows explorer and paste it there to acces files or folders

Comment: [this post](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/2-ways-generate-link-shared-network-folder-or-library) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

It should be in the format

```
file://server/folder/file.ext
```

That's **two** slashes at the beginning. So you need to convert backslashes to forward slashes, and escape any non-URL-allowed characters (e.g. space -> %20).

To make this easier, I use [SendTo Toys](http://www.gabrieleponti.com/software/), and set the following options:

[image: SendTo Toys clipboard options]

Bear in mind that this will create a link, and allow you to copy it, but clicking it to open may **not** work, due to security settings on your PC.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little embarrassing to admit that with experimentation I have discovered that there is a fairly simple workaround for the issue.
If the last stanza of the URI is broken - include a dir slash after it.
For the example:
 
\server\share name\second stanza\thirdstanza\fourth stanza
We only need ping
\server\share name\second stanza\thirdstanza\fourth stanza\
It works for me when sending folder names.  Please try it in your applications.